# How can I undo ending a flight accidentally?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So I had this awesome station orbiting [Tylo](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Tylo) with a lander and crew there already so that I could (hopefully) perform the landing the next time I played.  So having had enough for the day, I proceed to get myself back to the title screen, but in the process, accidentally hit the end flight button instead of the space station button.  "Oh no, what have!?!" and I frantically try holding F9 to reload the quicksave I had *just* made, try putting another rocket on the pad and doing the same thing, all with no luck.

If I accidentally end a flight, and I know prior to ending the flight I have a good save, is there any way to recover it?  Assume any persistence and quicksave file backups aren't recent enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>While you can't undo an end flight (well, at least not without a stringent backup policy), you can prevent yourself from accidentally clicking the end flight button (and then confirming said action) with [this mod](http://kerbalspaceport.com/g_lockflight-7/).  Of course, even this isn't fool-safe, as you have to enable the option to begin with.  Also, there is the possibility that it will get disabled if you start undocking parts.  With my brief testing, it looks like if one piece of a station was set to block end flight, the entire station will block as well.</strike>

---

Previous answer kept for posterity.  The game mechanics for ending a flight were drastically changed in version 0.21 such that it's much harder to do accidentally.  Yes, it's possible to revert the state of a flight to an earlier point (a quick-save, the launch, or the VAB/SPH), but this is much less destructive compared to ending a flight.

You can still end a flight from the tracking station (by "recovering" vessels that have landed on Kerbin or "terminating" others), but since this is a much more deliberate action, it's less likely that you'll end a critical flight accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading a quicksave works perfectly fine in that situation. If it does not bring you back to your lost ship, you should be able to select it in the tracking station.

Comment: Nope, did not work.